# Zuul Proxy : o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping : No routes found from RouteLocator

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, cloud-foundry

I am new to PCF and I have created a zuul routing spring boot app and deployed the cloud.
My PCF Route for this router app is domain.cfd2.checkFinancial.com.

I want to route the call to "https://domain.cfd2.checkFin.com/cardmembersvcs/acs" to our internal server https://vst0.mapi.checkFin.com/

Below is my Application.yml / Zuul Mapping :

```
---
spring:
 profiles: default

zuul:
 routes:
  cloud:
   path: /cardsvcs/acs/**
   sensitiveHeaders: 
   url: https://vst0.mapi.checkFin.com/cardsvcs/acs/
   stripPrefix: false

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false
```

So this set up run perfect when I run from the local, and I hit 
/cardsvcs/acs/test/api and request is routed to /vst0.mapi.checkFin.com/cardsvcs/acs/test/api

But when I hit the Cloud URL from Postman domain.cfd2.checkFin.com/cardmembersvcs/acs/test/api, I get a 404 and I see in the logs the warning "
2017-05-15T15:46:37.000+00:00 [APP] OUT 2017-05-15 15:46:37.399 WARN 19 --- **[nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping : No routes found from RouteLocator**"

Shouldn't any route containing /cardsvcs/acs/** be mapped?

Comment: Is your CF logs throwing any errors. cf logs [AppName] --recent will get you the logs. Just check that.

Comment: There is no error as such. It just gives me a warning I mentioned. It says :WARN 19 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Noutes found from RouteLocator

Comment: Your configuration looks good. Do you have @EnableZuulProxy in your spring boot main class... ????

Comment: Yes I do. This set up works on my local, when I hit localhost it does route. It gives me this error only when I try to hit it on the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable zuul Proxy in your main class with `@EnableZuulProxy`.

I am sure you will not get below error message in your server logs, however:

```
[nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping : No routes found from RouteLocator"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are mapping requests to Zuul host like: `http://<zuul>/cardsvcs/acs....` via:

```
path: /cardsvcs/acs/**
```

But a route mapping for `http://<zuul>/cardmembersvcs/acs` is missing

Comment: what do you mean by zuul host here?

Comment: Zuul host is where Zuul app was deployed